# TF Api Dataset: initialization

Tags: tensorflow, dataset

The `tf.dataset` works really greate, I was able to speed up learning ~2x. But I have still performance problem, the utilization of GPU is low (despite using `tf.dataset` with several workers). 
My use case is following:

1. ~400 of training examples, each have 10 input channels (take ~5GB)
2. The task is segmentation using ResNet50. The forward-backward take ~0.15s. Batch size = 32
3. The data loading is fast, take ~0.06s.

But after one epoch (400/32 ~= 13 iteration), the data loading take ~3.5 seconds, same like initialization of loader (it is more than processing all epoch). This make learning very slow.

My question is: is there are option to eliminate initialization after each epoch, just continuously feed the data ?

I was trying to set `dataset.repeat(10)` but it does no help.

The loading code and train is here: https://gist.github.com/melgor/0e681a4fe8f125d25573aa30d8ace5f3

The model is just ResNet transformed to Ecnoder-Decoder idea for image segmentation. The most of the code is taken from https://github.com/argman/EAST, but as here loading is very slow, I would like to transform it to TfRecords.

Comment: It is hard to answer such questions without looking at the source. I have recently been playing with datasets and it seems that dataset.repeat() is the way to go rather than re-initializing the iterator every time. But you have to be careful about where in the pipeline you are doing the repeat().

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added some code if it could be useful for debuging. Currently I'm not sure if there is any method for resolving this issue.

Comment: Try to move repeat() before batch() and since you are using repeat() to control how many epochs of training you do, you can use one time iterator instead of initializeable one.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately it does not work better. Currently I'm trying to compress the data, maybe then re-initialization will work better.

Answer (score 0):

I partly resolve my problem with long initialization. I just make tge `tfrecord` file smaller. 
In my base implementation I used raw string as images (so string from numpy array). The new 'tfrecord' contain compressed images using `jpeg` or `png`. Thanks to that it make the file 50x smaller what make initialization much faster. But there is also the cons of it: your images need to be uini8 (jpeg) or uint16 (png). In case of float, you can use uint16 but there will loss of information.

For encoding numpy array to compressed sting you can use Tensorflow itself:

```
encoded_jpeg = tf.image.encode_jpeg(tf.constant(img),format='rgb').eval(session=sess)
encoded_png  = tf.image.encode_png(tf.constant(png_image)).eval(session=sess)
```